# "We'll sit tight"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Context:

> Hagen said quickly and proudly, "I was as good a son to him as you or
> Mike, maybe better. I'm giving you a professional opinion. Personally
> I want to kill all those bastards." The emotion in his voice shamed
> Sonny, who said, "Oh, Christ, Tom, I didn't mean it that way." But he
> had, really. Blood was blood and nothing else was its equal.
>
> Sonny brooded for a moment as the others waited in embarrassed silence.
> then he sighed and spoke quietly. "OK, we'll **sit tight** until the old
> man can give us the lead.
>
> (from *The Godfather*, by Puzo)

What is the meaning of *we'll sit tight*  here?

Comment: It's an idiom.  If you look up *sit* in many dictionaries it will list *sit tight* also.

Comment: Vote to reopen. It is not intuitively obvious that *sit tight* is an idiom. So it would not necessarily be obvious to look up *sit tight* in a dictionary.

Comment: When providing context, you need to also include the **source**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Remain firmly in one’s place:
>
> 1.1. Refrain from taking action or changing one’s mind:

Have you tried to consult a dictionary? See the [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sit-tight?q=sit+tight) for the above. Here, the meaning is  figurative because the person in your question might not be sitting tight physically, so 1.1 is the best definition.
To rewrite your quote:

> "OK, we **will NOT take any action** until the old man can give us the lead.